# C++ non-polymorphic interface

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

Simply put, how do you create an interface in C++ for a single level of inheritance (for simplicity and didactic reasons)? I saw some code that wasn't using polymorphism, but where the base class contained a virtual abstract method (`virtual void TheMethod() = 0`).

Now a class was derived from this abstract class with the pure virtual method, but in the subsequent code, instances of the derived class were used without dynamic allocation at all.

Is this the correct way to do it? What about the overhead inferred by the usage of a polymorphic design?

I presume this is out of the question.. this looks more like hiding/ghosting the base method, even if that method is a pure virtual one.

*Later edit*: thanking all the people that managed to provide some good answers, I'd like to underline a critical error that arose from the usage of "dynamic allocation" with the meaning of emphasizing this object creation possibility as the only one compatible with polymorphism. It is quite clear that it is not the only way (but maybe the most common?) to make use of this run-time call behavior, but to further clarify my original question:

**Is there a way to force a programmer to implement a method without using pure virtual methods?** My perhaps unjustified concern is whether or not having opened the gate to polymorphic design is also a bit heavy on the performance side (talking thousands of such calls per second to the method in discussion).

*Even later edit*: making the base have a protected constructor means it cannot be instantiated directly (apart from using factories or other friendly means) and this could solve compensate for one of the effects a pure virtual methods induces. But how to make sure any derived class still provides its own method implementation? If the maybe exaggerated concern of having an associated vtable is really not that big of a deal, I'll stick to using the pure virtual method (since SFINAE the curiously recurring template pattern is more difficult to read and understand by people that are not at least intermediate C++ programmers - like me :) ).

Comment: Dynamic allocation has nothing to do with OOP and polymorphism in particular.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but even without dynamic allocation, a pointer/reference to this derived class can be used where a pointer/reference to the base class is expected. Furthermore, the overhead in this case is likely to be very small (at most a single additional pointer per instance, and some extra indirection in some function calls).

Comment: @Lyth Yes and no.  The whole point of using polymorphic objects is that you don't know the type of the object until runtime, which pretty much requires dynamic allocation.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Also yes and no. It can make sense to use dynamic binding even if the actual type is known at compile time: The alternative would be use templates but you may want to have stuff in separate compilation units and still be able to handle more than one type that satisfies a given interface.

Comment: @JamesKanze Dynamic allocation is not necessary for an object to act polymorphically. No matter how derived objects were created or where they reside, you can act on them through a base class without knowing any implementation details (consider a static pool of all sorts of objects).

Comment: @bitmask Yes.  There are special cases.  I've worked on projects where interfaces were used for hiding (rather than the compilation firewall idiom).  But even there, the factory function which returns a pointer to the base must put the actual object somewhere, and dynamic allocation is almost the only choice.

Comment: @Lyth Dynamic allocation isn't necessary for an object to act polymorphically, but it is necessary if the type isn't known until runtime, and practically, except for pedagogical reasons, they main reason to use polymorphism is because the type won't be known until runtime.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm just trying to stress on that these principles are distinct, despite that they are most often used together. For pedagogical purposes, of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as others have stated you basically use classes with pure virtual (abstract) member functions and no data members. When *implementing* this interface, naturally you have to provide these methods.

This, on the other hand has nothing to do with dynamic allocation. Whether you have automatic objects (i.e. stack) or dynamic objects (i.e. heap) is irrelevant for how you use them, including polymorphy. Do you mean dynamic *binding*?

Now, having said all that, you *can* implement an interface without using dynamic binding (i.e. "polymorphism") with templates. Basically, you would use SFINAE+CRTP to check if a given member function exists by privately inheriting from a template class. Basically, your parent class (which contains no virtual members) `template <typename T> class FooIface;` (inherited from as `class Foo : private FooIface<Foo>`) would make sure `T` has the member function `foo` by trying to call it. Using meta-programming tricks you can also make sure `foo` has the correct type.

But this would probably be too cumbersome and too hard to read. An abstract base class is the common approach.

Comment: for now this is the closest thing to an answer, although the rest of the answers are also providing more than satisfactory insights on what could and should be done. the template way is just the good solution candidate to my stupid cpp puzzle

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to allocate an object dynamically to use it polymorphically:

```
struct base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct derived : base {
    virtual void foo() {
        // do stuff
    }
};

void f(base& object) {
    object.foo();
}

int main() {
    derived object; // no dynamic allocation at all
    f(object); // polymorphism happens here
}
```

Comment: The fact that the signature of `f` uses a reference, counts for a dynamic mechanism being involved somehow, hence the polymorphic use, or am I getting the wrong picture? I should have stated that no pointers, nor references are to be used to allow for polymorphic effects. Just stack allocated objects for a very simple purpose. Alas, perhaps there's really no big worry for the overhead.. for simple scenarios.

Comment: @toedron: if no pointers or references are used, then agreed you're not using runtime polymorphism. For example, `derived object; object.foo();` behaves exactly as if `foo` were a non-virtual function. It will most likely also *perform* as if `foo` were a non-virtual function. There's nothing "incorrect" about calling `foo` like that, but if the classes `base` and `derived` were intended only ever to be used in that way, then it was pointless to make `foo` virtual in `base`, and for that matter pointless for `base` to exist at all. Does `base` ever call the pure virtual function?

Comment: ... because if so remember that `this` is a pointer, and `base` then is indeed using runtime polymorphism via `this`.

Comment: This is done a lot in the Doom3 source, as well as Valve's Source engine (though, they tend to use pointers instead of references). They do this for performance reasons to avoid vtable look-ups. There is a further discussion on this here: http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/x3bqg/doom_3_vtable_trick/

Comment: @SteveJessop yes, I was talking about a very specific scenario where, as much as possible, no pointer or references are used to enforce polymorphic interpretation. I was aiming for an interface enforcement, but not necessarily dependent on virtual functions and their real meaning. As I am currently aware, one cannot declare an abstract class without having a `virtual` specifier for a method. I saw tens of classes that had virtual methods with no intended use of polymorphism in the code-base of the projects. That, of course, did not mean a third party couldn't have used the class otherwise.

Comment: I don't think there's much value in C++, in using an abstract base class to declare that a class implements a particular interface, but then never actually refer to instances of the class via that base class. If you want non-runtime polymorphism, then you do it with templates and "duck typing" for now, perhaps with a type trait `is_a_base<derived>` so you can write code that checks it. Then you wait for the committee to finally get around to implementing Concepts.

Answer (score 5):

For didactic reasons, if the goal is to understand how to implement
polymorphic objects in C++, and test the types one has created, dynamic
allocation isn't necessary.  In a real application, however, it probably
will be, since the principal reason for using polymorphism is because
the concrete type will not be known until runtime.

Note that in C++ (and in practically every other language which supports
it), polymorphism requires reference semantics, rather than the value
semantics which C++ uses by default.  Typically, a class designed to be
used as a base class will *not* support copy and assignment (except
possibly via a virtual `clone()` function).

With regards to the overhead: compared to what?  Calling a virtual
function is typically more expensive than calling a non-virtual
function.  But if you're using virtual functions, it is because you need
runtime dispatch; simulating this using some other mechanism is likely
to be even more expensive.

Comment: The biggest cost of virtual functions is not the pointer indirection itself, but rather the opportunity costs of preventing inlining.

Comment: @rhalbersma If the function can be inlined otherwise.  In a lot of cases, what you say is true, but it also depends on the architecture.  On the old HP-PA, a virtual function call purged the pipeline, which made it very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of ***Interface*** in C++,
You can *only simulate* the behavior using an **[Abstract class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr142.htm)**.
Abstract class is a class which has atleast one pure virtual function, One cannot create any instances of an abstract class but You could create pointers and references to it. Also each class inheriting from the abstract class must implement the pure virtual functions in order that it's instances can be created.

***Dynamic allocation*** and ***Polymorphism*** are not related!

***Dynamic allocation*** defines ***where*** the object will be allocated and that the object shall have explicit memory management unlike the implicit memory management provided for automatic variables.

***Polymorphism*** means ***multiple forms of one thing***. That is same function having different behaviors in classes.You can have a Base class pointer pointing to an object on stack and still have polymorphic behavior.

Comment: The concept of _interface_ is independent of the language (and shouldn't be confused with the keyword `interface` used in some languages).  C++, in fact, offers far better support for the concept of interface than do many of the languages which have the keyword.  And in practice, if the exact type won't be known until runtime, the objects will have to be allocated dynamically (and reference semantics will have to be used---polymorphic object types will normally not support copy and assignment).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree on concept of *interface* being independent of a language. Also, in practice it is true that *Polymorphism* **needs** *Dynamic Allocation*, but the confusion with OP seems to be confusing the *need* with *necessity* which is not the case, and hence the stress on two concepts not being related.

Comment: Perhaps a more correct formulation would be that the reasons which lead you to use polymorphism will also lead you to use dynamic allocation.  The abstract concepts aren't related (which is what I think you're trying to say), but in practice, the two tend to go together, because the same reasons motivate both.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I suppose the counter-example from the standard is the iostreams library, which is polymorphic but usually not dynamically allocated. Implementing `ostream &operator<<(ostream &)` might be in some sense nicer than implementing `template <typename STREAM> STREAM &operator<<(STREAM &)`. Then again, that library is not held up by many people as best practice in C++ design (and my own example `operator<<` is problematic because it returns a different type from its argument), so...

Comment: @SteveJessop The `istream` and `ostream` classes are **not** polymorphic; none of the member functions are virtual.  `std::streambuf` is polymorphic, and you might have a point in its regard; in early implementations, they were usually dynamically allocated, but it's now more frequent that they be a member or a private base of the derived `[io]stream` class.  This does seem to be an exception, however.